# How can $\mathbb{C}^m$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$ each be a complex subspace of $\mathbb{C}^m \times \mathbb{C}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

The problem from "Quantum Computing for Computer Scientists" states: Show that $\mathbb{C}^m$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$ are each a complex subspace of  $\mathbb{C}^m \times \mathbb{C}^n$.

The solution says: An element $[c_0, c_1, ..., c_{m - 1}]^T$ of $\mathbb{C}^m$ can be seen as the element $\langle [c_0, c_1, ..., c_{m - 1}]^T, [0, 0, ..., 0]^T \rangle$ of $\mathbb{C}^m \times \mathbb{C}^n$.

I don't see how this could possibly be correct because I disagree that $\mathbb{C}^m \subseteq \mathbb{C}^m \times \mathbb{C}^n$. Elements of direct sums of two vector spaces are ordered pairs of vectors, $(v_1, v_2)$ while elements of vector spaces are vectors, $v_1$.

As a counterexample, they have two different zero vectors! The zero vector of $\mathbb{C}^2$ is $[0, 0]^T$, while the zero vector of $\mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^3$ is $([0, 0]^T, [0, 0, 0]^T)$.

Hence, $[0, 0]^T \notin \mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^3$. Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that $\mathbb{C}^m$ and $\mathbb{C}^m$ are each **isomorphic** to a complex subspace of  $\mathbb{C}^m \times \mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: $\mathbb C^m$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb C^m\times \mathbb C^n$, however, it's indeed isomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb C^m\times \mathbb C^n$...

Comment: yes, "isomorphic to", or "naturally isomorphic to", because it is expected from the context that you have the decomposition $V\times W\simeq V\times \{0\} \oplus \{0\}\times W$

Comment: Isomorphism is implicitly referred to here, as is often the case with set inclusions. One might say that $\Bbb C^m$ can be *identified* (in) (as a subspace of) $\Bbb C^m\times\Bbb C^n$